# How to assign live time to a variable

Tags: swift, timer

I have a dictionary of values (dataValues) that I ultimately display in a table view. I need to display the current time as a string in that dictionary. dataValues gets its values from the Calculations app in a model file, where I perform my calculations.

I've tried appending currentTime to dataValues, but given it's a dictionary of type string:any it obvbiously doesn't work.

```
var dataValues : [String:Any]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataValues = Calculations.shared.ecefToData()

    var timer = Timer()
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.tick) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
var currentTime: String = "00:00:00"
@objc func tick() -> String {
     currentTime = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(),
                                                     dateStyle: .short,
                                                     timeStyle: .medium)
    return currentTime
    print(currentTime)

}
```

}

I would like to append the current time to dataValues and have the time constantly update while in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload your tableView every time you update your currentTime value, but I'm not sure that's the best way to handle that.

You could instead tie a timer directly to a label on your tableview cell and have it update repeatedly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I simply chose to assign the current time to the detailView.text label if the index row was equal to zero as I wanted to display time in the top row of the table view.